# Dragonfly doesn't print characters requiring pressing Alt Gr, such as { or [

Tags: python, python-dragonfly

I have installed Python 2.7.14, pywin 2.7, natlink 4.1victor and dragonfly 0.6.6b1. I have windows 10 where the main language is English, but the keyboard layout is in Finnish.

If I go to Notepad and edit voice commands, a test command like this:

```
Test command = "xx{hello[] | world}";
```

Outputs "`xx7hello89 < world0`" with a Finnish keyboard layout, and "`xx[hello[] \ world]`" with a *US English* one.

When using a Finnish keyboard, this looks as if someone tried to type those characters but didn't press **Alt Gr** (for example a curly bracket is done by pressing **Alt Gr + 7**)

There’s a similar but slightly different problem with ready-made grammars for programming languages, except here the curly brackets don’t show at all.

For example when I use `_cs_grammar.py` with a Finnish keyboard layout, saying “`for loop`“ produces just "`for(;;)`" and a couple of new lines. Interestingly, when I set the keyboard to US English what it produces is "`for*<<(`" and no curly brackets either.

```
"for loop": Text("for(;;) {") + Key("enter")+ Key("enter") + Text("}")
```

I'm trying to code using voice recognition, and characters like those not working is hardly ideal. Where and how is a keypress like that defined?

Answer (score 1):

Dragonfly has historically (t4ngo/dragonfly) had issues with alternate keyboard layouts. This is been fixed in the community fork of dragonfly.

I recommend using [Dictation Toolbox fork of dragonfly](https://github.com/Danesprite/dragonfly) which is integrating fixes from the community. Hopefully these fixes will be pulled into into the main promoted repository t4ngo/dragonfly someday.

The issue that's relevant to fix alternate keyboard layouts.
https://github.com/dictation-toolbox/dragonfly/issues/16

Let me know this resolves your issue.